# Using column value as column name in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, unpivot

I'm working with a legacy DB that has a table that houses field names from other tables.

So I have this structure:

```
Field_ID | Field_Name
*********************
1 | Col1  
2 | Col2  
3 | Col3  
4 | Col4
```

and I need to pull a list of this field metadata along with the values of that field for a given user. So I need:

```
Field_ID | Field_Name | Value  
1 | Col1 | ValueOfCol1onADiffTable  
2 | Col2 | ValueOfCol2onADiffTable  
3 | Col3 | ValueOfCol3onADiffTable  
4 | Col4 | ValueOfCol4onADiffTable
```

I'd like to use the Field_Name in a subquery to pull that value, but can't figure out how to get SQL to evaluate `Field_Name` as a column in the sub-query.

So something like this:

```
select
        Field_ID
      ,Field_Name
      ,(SELECT f.Field_Name from tblUsers u 
    where u.User_ID = @userId) as value
from 
  dbo.tblFields f
```

But that just returns `Field_Name` in the values column, not the value of it.

Do I need to put the sub-query in a separate function and evaluate that? Or some kind of dynamic SQL?

Comment: A table has _columns_, not _fields_.

Comment: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE or similar depending on your RDBMS

Comment: @jarlh - understood. I didn't write the original schema and don't have the option of changing it. The names of the columns in this case are Field_Name, etc

Comment: @Randy - MSSQL, sql server 2016 I believe

Comment: What flavor and version of SQL?

Comment: MSSQL, ~~ sql server 2016~~ EDIT: sql server 10.5 (2008)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL server this would require dynamic SQL and  UNPIVOT notation.
<kbd>**[see working demo](http://rextester.com/TVDHEC7582)**</kbd>

```
create table tblFields (Field_ID int ,Field_Name varchar(10));
insert into tblFields values
(1,'Col1')
,(2,'Col2')
,(3,'Col3')
,(4,'Col4');
declare @userId int
set @userId=1

create table tblUsers (User_ID int, col1 varchar(10),col2 varchar(10));
insert into tblUsers values
(1, 10,100),
(2,20,200);

declare @collist varchar(max)
declare @sqlquery varchar(max)

select @collist= COALESCE(@collist + ', ', '') + Field_Name
from dbo.tblFields
where exists (
       select * from sys.columns c join sys.tables t 
       on c.object_id=t.object_id and t.name='tblUsers'
       and c.name =Field_Name)
select @sqlquery=
' select Field_ID ,Field_Name, value '+
' from dbo.tblFields f  Join '+
' ( select  * from '+
'( select * '+
' from tblUsers u '+
' where u.User_ID = '+ cast(@userId as varchar(max)) +
' ) src '+
'unpivot ( Value for field in ('+ @collist+')) up )t'+
' on t.field =Field_Name'
exec(@sqlquery)
```

Comment: demo works as expected, but one wrinkle... I simplified my example. The real world version needs to look in two different tables for 'value' tblUsers and tblusers_program_history_detail. I can join them but then sql complains  because it has two instances of user_id on it

Comment: the dynamic sql statement I'm using:

`select Field_ID
   ,(case when DB_Field_Name is null then Field_Name else DB_Field_Name end) as FieldName
   ,Field_Name
   ,DB_Field_Name
      ,Proper_Label
      ,FieldCategory
   ,FieldValue 
from 
  dbo.tblBiographic_Fields f 
  join (SELECT * from
   (select * from tblUsers  u inner join tblusers_program_history_detail h
 on u.User_ID = h.User_ID
 where h.User_ID = 1) src
   unpivot (FieldValue for field in (' + @cols + ')) up )t
   on t.field = DB_Field_Name`

Comment: @SamR. you can also look into union of `tblUsers` and `tblusers_program_history_detail` for relevant columns

Comment: You should be explicitly putting a list of columns here instead of * : `select * from tblUsers u inner join tblusers_program_history_detail`

Comment: Don't tables have to have the same # of columns for union?

Comment: Dhruv - subbing in the columns variable ((select ' + @cols + ' from tblUsers  u inner join tblusers_program_history_detail h) gets me further, no more syntax errors. But `The type of column "Initial" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.`

EDIT: missed that "Initial" is the name of an actual column in tblUsers. That column is a nullable varchar(1)

Comment: recreatable in the demo by changing the length of col2 in table declaration


`create table tblUsers (User_ID int, col1 varchar(10),col2 varchar(1));`

Comment: Resolved by casting the columns to varchars of the same size